# How will jQuery Document ready behave in a dynamically inserted script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

What if the below script is dynamically inserted into the page after the DOM has been loaded...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log("Will anybody see me?");
});
```

Will that debug statement still fire?

Comment: why dont you try it yourself?

Comment: Yes... but can also be tested easily yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a `document.ready` handler *after* the event has fired, then it will be invoked immediately.